# Swift on Apple Watch: reloadTimeline(for complication) freezes UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication, dispatch-queue

I use the method below in my watchOS app whenever the data changes which should be reflected in the complication.
The problem is that executing this method makes my UI freeze for a few seconds. If I remove the `reloadTimeline` call the problem disappears.
First I thought the problem is that this is executed on the main thread but the problem remains when pushing the work on a background thread (`DispatchQueue.global().async {}` or `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {}`). Maybe that is because the work is pushed back on the main thread no matter what.

How can I execute this method without freezing the UI?

This is by the way the exact same code snipped presented at https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10049.

```swift
import ClockKit

enum ComplicationUpdater {

    static func updateActiveComplications() {
        let complicationServer = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()

        if let activeComplications = complicationServer.activeComplications {

            for complication in activeComplications {

                complicationServer.reloadTimeline(for: complication)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My solution for now is to only call this method when the app moves into the background. This updates the complication when the user clicks the crown and the update is immediately reflected in the watch face. But if I decide to use the app again within about 10 seconds I get the freeze/lag.